# Update defined password from a form

Tags: php

I have a php file where i defined user id and password like this

```
define( 'USER', "abc@example.com" );
define( 'PASSWORD', "abc@123" );
```

Now i want to change the password with change password form. Please help me, how i can do this. Form is simple like this

```
 <form name="changepassword" action="password.php" method="post">
    <label>New password</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: "Change password with change password..." what exactly you need, after submit, it will redirected to password.php page....need some more desc.

Comment: Don't use `define` to keep track of a password.. its a `constant` for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the password as a constant in your code it can not be simply changed using a form. a simple solution to be able to change the password would be to store it in a file. when there is a post reqeust update the file.

it could for example look like this:

```
$pwFile = '/path/to/password.txt';

if (isset($_POST) && array_key_exists('password', $_POST)) {

    if (is_writable($pwFile)) {

        file_put_contents($_POST['password'], $pwFile);
        $updated = 1;

    } else {

        $updated = 0;  
    }

    header('Location: password.php?updated='. $updated);
    exit(0);
}

if (is_file($pwFile) && is_readable($pwFile)) {

    $password =  file_get_contents($pwFile);

} else {

    $password = 'd3f4ul7p455w0rd';
}

define('PASSWORD', $password);

if (isset($_GET['updated'])) {

    if (1 == $_GET['updated']) {

        echo 'password updated';

    } else {

        echo 'could not update password';
    }
}
```

Comment: Store password in `.txt` file? Why?

Comment: so do you want to explain a rookie how to properly use a database with encrypted, salted and peppered passwords? this is just a simple solution for him he will be able to understand ;) so please undo your -1. or you you have a better idea to bring him forward without dispairing him ;)

Comment: Telling one with a question about passwords to store the passwords in text files is an unsafe way and surely not a good answer. So the -1 for your answer is justly... You could have pointed the OP to some tutorials...

Comment: of course its not safe but its the most simple solution for what he asked for :P i would have added some hash algo but it would only confuse him right now :P also he did not ask for a secure solution ;)